# Download large hidden image after initial rendering

Tags: image, rendering

My website displays thumbnail images. When the user clicks on an image, the image is displayed in a larger size. The images themselves exist in two sizes, the thumbnail size for fast rendering and then the larger size.

Initially the thumbnail size is downloaded and displayed. What I want is for the larger images to be downloaded (but be hidden) once the page has rendered/loaded. That way, the initial rendering is fast, but, when the user clicks on the thumbnail, the image is already downloaded.

At first I did this by

```
<div name = "big_path" style= "display:hidden" src == "" path = "big/path"></div>
```

In js/jquery, after loading, I then set the src attribute to path, causing the image to be downloaded. I do not use this div element for anything except to download the image.

This works in IE, but Chrome does not download hidden images. Therefore, the image is first downloaded when the user clicks on the thumbnail. Maybe this is fast enough, but I'd prefer to already have the image downloaded.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to make the div visible, but make it 1px by 1px. And then I made it a span, not div:

```
<span name = "big_path" style = "width:1px; height:1px" src == "" path = "big/path"></span>
```

And then I still set src = path once the initial rendering is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //load images
    //append images
});
```

Basically, you are loading the large images after the document has loaded. After that, you are appending the images like this:

```
$('.thumbnail').append('<img src="img/lol.jpeg" />');
```

You may want to put this in a for loop for lots of thumbnails.

Another solution is to use [progressive jpegs](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/).

Comment: Ill look into progressive images, thanks. Maybe my question wasn't clear, but what I needed to know was how to load the images while having them remain invisible/hidden. But I figured it out, see other answer.

Comment: Probably not the most semantic way to solve this problem but it works ...so good :)